# manage bean Session scoped injected into a servlet is creating a new instance

Tags: servlets, cdi, payara

I am injecting a managebean with session scope into a servlet, however every servlet invocation is being created a new instance of manage beean. How do I make the servlet work with the same instance created after login?
I use Java JDK 8 and payara server 5

Comment: From which package did you import the `@SessionScoped` annotation? There are multiple in Java EE and only one of them is correct for CDI.

Comment: Hi, my import is javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped. From what I saw, by injecting the dependency it rebuilds the manageBean session scope and the FacesContext gets null.

Comment: There's no `FacesContext` available in a servlet at all. Now this looks more like a http://xyproblem.info What are you trying to do?